# What insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, arthropod

I found it in Russia.

[image: Insect in question]

Where do they usually live? What do they eat?

Full length is approximately 2 cm.

Comment: Terrestrial crustacean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be it's a Woodlouse!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse

Comment: And, of course, whatever it is it isn't an insect.

Comment: Indeed, by true definition you are looking at a crustacean instead of an insect. The differentiation can be made because crustaceans are biramous, meaning their "legs" have two segments instead of the typical one in most insects.

Comment: @MichaelCannon.. arachnid perhaps ??

Comment: @WYSIWYG it has 12 legs, arachnids have 8 by definition. The woodlouse/pill bug is in the subphylum of Crustacea.

Comment: and interestingly, woodlice are said to be delicious in a soup!

Answer (score 6):

This is a terrestrial [isopod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopoda) [crustacean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crustacean) called a woodlouse ([colloquially referred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodlouse#Common_names) to as pill bugs, potato bugs, roly-pollies, sow bugs, etc.).

[image]

There are over 5000 species in the world with at least 64 in Russia (see [Kuznetsova & Gongalsky 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3335401/)).

**Habitat**:

Woodlice are typically found in damp, dark places -- in the soil, under rocks/logs/debris, etc.

> Living in a terrestrial environment, woodlice breathe through trachea-like lungs in their paddle-shaped hind legs (pleopods), called pleopodal lungs. Woodlice need moisture because they rapidly lose water by excretion and through their cuticle, and so are usually found in damp, dark places

**Description**:

As with all Arthropoda, the woodlouse is a segmented animal with a rigid exoskeleton and jointed limbs.

- However, this is *not* an insect! Insects have 3 pairs of legs while isopods have 7 pairs of legs.

The extended uropods on your specimen as well as the pereon-pleon junction, number of antenna flagella, etc. all are important for IDing to species. (E.g., see [here](http://pick4.pick.uga.edu/mp/20q?guide=Oniscidea&flags=col4:gleansubgenus)).

Note: although many people associate these arthropods with the ability to roll up into a perfect ball, only woodlice in the genus Armadillidium and in the family Armadillidae can roll up into an almost perfect sphere as a defensive mechanism.

**Diet**:

Woodlice are generally [detritivores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detritivore), meaning they eat decaying organic matter.

---

Citations:

<sup>Kuznetsova, Daria M., and Konstantin B. Gongalsky. "Cartographic analysis of woodlice fauna of the former USSR." ZooKeys 176 (2012): 1.</sup>